# Convert LISTAGG to XMLAGG Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg, string-aggregation

I have a below SQL and I am trying to convert the LISTAGG to XMLAGG.  My DB version is 12.1 and hence LISTAGG is not supporting more than 4K characters.

Orignal Query :--

```
SELECT LISTAGG (se1.EMAIL, ', ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY se1.EMAIL)
AS listofsgs
FROM abc se1, xyz team , mno sne
                WHERE     team.employee_id = se1.employee_id
                      AND sne.non_employee_id = team.non_employee_id
```

Transformed Query :--

```
SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(se1.EMAIL||',')).EXTRACT('//text()')  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY se1.EMAIL)
AS listofsgs
FROM abc se1, xyz team , mno sne
   WHERE     team.employee_id = se1.employee_id
   AND sne.non_employee_id = team.non_employee_id
```

But whenever I run it it keeps failing with Syntax error of missing comma. Is my transformed query correct or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and below worked for me:

```
Select RTRIM((XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, se1.EMAIL || ',') ORDER BY se1.EMAIL).EXTRACT ('//text()')).getclobval(),',') listofsgs
FROM abc se1, xyz team , mno sne
   WHERE     team.employee_id = se1.employee_id
   AND sne.non_employee_id = team.non_employee_id
```

Please note: I am adding getclobval() because I was getting "ORA-19011 : Character string buffer too small error". You can remove it if you do not need it.

Comment: Worked as a charm, this is the more correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query as the replacement for `LISTAGG`

```
SELECT RTRIM (
          XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, se1.email || ',') ORDER BY se1.email).EXTRACT (
             '//text()'),
          ',')
          listofsgs
  FROM abc se1, xyz team, mno sne
 WHERE     team.employee_id = se1.employee_id
       AND sne.non_employee_id = team.non_employee_id
```

Answer (score -1):

try this query :

```
SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e,se1.EMAIL||',')).EXTRACT('//text()', ',')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY se1.EMAIL)
    AS listofsgs
    FROM abc se1, xyz team , mno sne
       WHERE     team.employee_id = se1.employee_id
       AND sne.non_employee_id = team.non_employee_id;
```

Comment: It fails at the Group saying From keyword not found .

Comment: try SELECT by  SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e,se1.EMAIL||',')).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',') AS listofsgs FROM abc se1, xyz team , mno sne WHERE team.employee_id = se1.employee_id AND sne.non_employee_id = team.non_employee_id;

Comment: with RTRIM added and commenting that WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY se1.EMAIL) works for me ...  select should be  SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e,se1.EMAIL||',')).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',')

    AS listofsgs